# How to configure Atom editor to property work with Python files indented by spaces?

Tags: python, atom-editor

It seems that when I use <kbd>Tab</kbd>/<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to indent/unindent blocks of code in Python code, Atom will use tabs, even if the file was using only spaces.

Has anyone solved the problem of working with Python files in Atom (keeping the tabs or spaces consistent in the file, so they don't mix)?

Comment: What're your *Tab Type* and *Tab Length* settings, globally and for language-python?

Comment: I was able to get the desired behaviour after changing Tab Type to soft from Auto. Still no idea where are the language specific settings.

Comment: *Settings* > *Packages* > *language-python*